# Why specify the target architecture to the linker?

Tags: c, linker, embedded, newlib

I've been working on using the Meson build system for an embedded project.  Since I'm working on an embedded platform, I've written a custom linker script and also an invocation for the linker.  I didn't have any problems until I tried to link in `newlib` to my project, when I started to have link issues. Just before I got it working, the last error was  `undefined reference to main` which I knew was clearly in the project.

Out of happenstance, I tried adding `-mcpu=cortex-m4` to my linker invocation (I am using `gcc` to link, I am told this is quite typical instead of directly calling `ld`).  It worked! Now, my only question is "why"?

Perhaps I am missing something about how the linking process actually works, but considering I am just producing an ELF file, I didn't think it would be important to specify the CPU architecture to the linker.  Is this a `newlib` thing, or has `gcc` just been doing magic behind the scenes for me that I haven't seen before?

For reference, [here's my project](https://github.com/PyroAVR/k64_base) (it's not complete)

Answer (score 1):

Such linker options ensure that the appropriate standard library and start-up code is linked when these are defaulted rather then explicitly specified or overridden.

The one ARM toolchain supports a variety of [ARM architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture) variants and options; they may be big or little-endian, have various instruction sets - ARM, Thumb. Thumb-2, ARM64 etc, and various extensions such a SIMD or DSP units.  The linker requires the architecture information to select the correct library to link for both performance and binary compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you should always link via the compiler driver (link forms of the `gcc` command), not via direct invocation of `ld`. If you're developing for bare metal on a particular exact target, it's possible to determine the set of linker arguments you need and use `ld` directly, but there's a lot that the compiler driver takes care of for you, and it's usually better to let it. (If you don't have a single fixed target, there are unlimited combinations of possibilities and no way you can reproduce all present and future ones someone may care about.)

You can still pass whatever options you like to the linker, e.g. custom linker scripts, via `-Wl,...` option forms.

As for why the specific target architecture ISA level could matter to linking, linking is not a dumb process of just sticking together binary chunks. Linking can involve patching up (relocations) or even generating (thunks for distant jump targets, etc.) code, in which case the linker may need to care what particular ISA level/variant it's targeting.

Comment: Right, that's the canonical advice I've heard - "don't call `ld` directly."  What I don't know is why I have to specify the target CPU when asking `gcc` to link pre-compiled objects.  Doesn't the architecture not matter when producing an ELF from `.o` files?

Comment: @PyroAVR There are addresses in object files and the linker resolves them into an exe or library. A linker uses a linker map to determine section entry points and offsets. Linker maps are device/operating system specific. So it does matter.

Comment: @BaileyKocin Correct me if I am wrong, but is a linker script the same as a linker map?  I am using a device-specific linker script, so shouldn't that be all the information the linker needs?

Comment: No you are right. A linker script defines everything. A linker map is just a pretty output of what the linker did. My bad.

Comment: But my comment still applies

Comment: @PyroAVR: Linking can involve patching up (relocations) or even generating (thunks for distant jump targets, etc.) code, in which case the linker may need to care what particular ISA level/variant it's targeting.

Comment: @R.. I did not consider the thunks problem.  Mind adding that to your main answer so other people can find it easy?  I understand much better now.